# Reloading mysql database from mysqldump file and ensuring integrity of read requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

I have a Rails web application that depends on a mysql database.

There is a script that runs `mysqldump` on *another* database and reloads the database above.

The commands are something like:

```
mysqldump -uuser1 -ppassword1 --opt db1 > dumpfile
```

and

```
mysql -uuser2 -ppassword2 db2 < dumpfile
```

The dump file is quite small (< 15MB).  Reloading the database from the dump file takes less than 150ms.

The dump file contains a series of sections like below:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `some_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `some_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `some_table`
--

LOCK TABLES `some_table` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `some_table` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES (1,...);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `some_table` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The Rails application is running when this happens.  (Let's assume that shutting down the Rails application before reloading the database is *not* an option.)

It's possible that a user web request may come in while the database is being reloaded.  If so, the integrity of the database read requests would be affected (for example, a table is empty), so the user would get an error or exception.  How do you avoid this?

Is there some way to ensure that no bad reads would happen while the database is being reloaded?  Such as, using transaction, lock the whole database, so that the read requests would *wait* until the database reload has completed?  How would I generated such a "read-safe" dumpfile (any option with mysqldump I should consider)?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess it depends on your configuration but I will tell you how we do it where I work.  First I will say that loading your db from a dump is largely considered bad practice.  We have a load balancer, so we basically just direct all traffic to a single instance while we import the dump on the other instance.  We then direct all traffic to the updated instance while the second instance updates.  Once both are updated we split the traffic between the 2 instances.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  In this case, the database is very small.  So I only need to guard against a very small time window.  Also this operation is part of the application, not part of the deployment process.  So an editor can trigger this event any time.  Do you change the load balancer manually or via a script?

Comment: We change it via script.  Have you verified that attempting to access the DB during the update will cause issues?  Personally I think the correct answer to this question is to not allow the user to trigger a dump from the UI but there may be some way to do it correctly that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Any transaction started as part of loading your dump file would be implicitly committed by the create table statements (this is true of most DDL statements in MySQL).

It does look like calling [`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html) acquires a global lock, which might be what you need.